# Why would a registrar not allow transfer-in of .ca domains?

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar, domain-transfer

I started at a company that had domain name registrations scattered among several different registrars. I wanted to consolidate all of these registrations to a single registrar to simplify management and renewal. I chose a registrar that supports all of the TLD's I wanted to use, but I was surprised to discover that this registrar doesn't allow `.ca` domains to be *transferred* in.

[image]

What is special about the `.ca` domain that would cause a registrar to not support transfers? Is this some kind of rule or procedure put in place by the domain registry?

Comment: .CA changed its backend last February and some things have changed, including transfers and notifications related to those. It may be the reason, or not. If you have a big enough volume of domains you should make sure to reach out to customer support of any given provider you decided to use and speak with them to see how they can help you consolidate your portfolio, at which point they should be able to let you know if they are able to handle incomining transfers for all TLDs you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CIRA, the registry for `.CA` among other things, changed its backend last February (see https://cira.ca/newsroom/cybersecurity/canadas-domain-now-powered-fury-registry-platform) and some things have changed, including transfers and notifications related to those. This impacted all registrars that had to adapt their systems.

It may be the reason, or not, only the registrar rejecting your command can really know what is wrong, what does it say?

If you have a big enough volume of domains you should make sure to reach out to customer support of any given provider you decided to use and speak with them to see how they can help you consolidate your portfolio, at which point they should be able to let you know if they are able to handle incoming transfers for all TLDs you are interested in.